# Using a .bat file to replace one file with another

Tags: batch-file

Does anyone know the script I'd need to use to replace one file with another, using a batch file.

Comment: You should be more specific.  Do you mean to place a file with the exact same name into the same location as the previous and delete the previous?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a while ago, we use it to update our Access database rollouts.

```
rem -- Set up the variables here.  
rem -- HDIR = Home Directory on local hard drive
rem -- PDIR = Location of Production version of database
rem -- PName = Name of database

Set HDIR=C:\Cigna\PIT
Set PDIR=\\Server051\Projects\Reporting\IntakeTool
Set PName=Intake_Tool.mdb


rem -- DO NOT EDIT ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE --

rem -- If the directory exists on the local hard drive, don't bother creating it
if exist "%HDIR%" GoTo DirDone
  md "%HDIR%"
:DirDone

rem -- Create a temp mapping since BAT files can't deal with UNCs
pushd %PDIR%

rem -- Copy the database and icon to the local hard drive, and the link to the desktop
Copy %PName% %HDIR%
```

Answer (score 0):

The following microsoft link covers the multiple different approaches you may take to accomplish this.

From the sounds of it, you are going to need to use the `/Y` switch.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/240268

Answer (score 0):

you can use xcopy to copy the content form one directory to another directory

XCopy /U D:\prac\a\1.txt D:\prac\b

I am attaching a screenshot in which both command to normal copy and overwrite copy are there 
[image: Xcopy with /U]

You can visit other options from link

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/240268][2]